# Pumping Lemma for regular language: Can we modify the first condition to 'for each i > 0'?

Tags: computer-science, regular-language, pumping-lemma, finite-state-automaton

Pumping lemma from <[Introduction_to_the_Theory_of_Computation](https://books.google.com/books/about/Introduction_to_the_Theory_of_Computatio.html?id=P3f6CAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button#v=onepage&q&f=false)>"

[image]

Question: Can we modify the first condition to `for each i > 0` instead of `for each i ≥ 0` ?

Comment: Yes, you can do this; however, all it does is make the pumping lemma less useful for no additional benefit. The pumping lemma for regular languages already cannot tell you that a language is regular, and it doesn't even necessarily work for all non-regular languages as it is. Restricting its applicability a little further is fine but unnecessary, especially since the method of proof implies that you can pump the substring down as well as up.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this.however it make the pumping lemma less useful . We use pumping lemma to tell a grammar is not regular and it doesn't even necessarily work for all non-regular languages  Restricting its applicability a little further is fine but unnecessary, especially since the method of proof implies that you can pump the substring down as well as up.